# divide array into smaller parts

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to divide a large byte array into smaller chunks (say 64 bytes). Please help me with this.

Comment: Sounds similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395547/how-to-get-a-sub-array-of-array-in-java-without-copying-data/

Answer (score 18):

Damian Vash's first method (the one using Arrays.copyOfRange()) adds zeros to the end of the last chunk if the input is not exactly a multiple of chunksize.

You might want to use this instead:

```
public static List<byte[]> divideArray(byte[] source, int chunksize) {

    List<byte[]> result = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    int start = 0;
    while (start < source.length) {
        int end = Math.min(source.length, start + chunksize);
        result.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(source, start, end));
        start += chunksize;
    }

    return result;
}
```

and in case it's useful, the same thing using ArrayList's:

```
  public static List<List<String>> divideList(List<String> source, int chunksize) {
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    int start = 0;
    while (start < source.size()) {
      int end = Math.min(source.size(), start + chunksize);
      result.add(source.subList(start, end));
      start += chunksize;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: How to divide bytes into 5 mb chunks using this ?

Answer (score 15):

You can use the method Arrays.copyOfRange(original, from, to)

```
 public static byte[][] divideArray(byte[] source, int chunksize) {


        byte[][] ret = new byte[(int)Math.ceil(source.length / (double)chunksize)][chunksize];

        int start = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
            ret[i] = Arrays.copyOfRange(source,start, start + chunksize);
            start += chunksize ;
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Or You can use as Max suggested the System.arraycopy

```
public static byte[][] divideArray(byte[] source, int chunksize) {


        byte[][] ret = new byte[(int)Math.ceil(source.length / (double)chunksize)][chunksize];

        int start = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
            if(start + chunksize > source.length) {
                System.arraycopy(source, start, ret[i], 0, source.length - start);
            } else {
                System.arraycopy(source, start, ret[i], 0, chunksize);
            }
            start += chunksize ;
        }


        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Beware that the second of these appears to allocate a "too large" of last chunk if source.length is not an even multiple of the chunksize...

Comment: How to divide bytes into 5 mb chunks using this ?

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ Just pass as chunk size 5000000 bytes. As 5MB = 5 Million Bytes.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking save some memory, a slight modification to Damian Vash's answer would help (in this case any remaining chunk is not allocated a complete 64 byte block size, as well...)

```
private byte[][] splitChunks(byte[] source)
{
    byte[][] ret = new byte[(int)Math.ceil(source.length / (double)CHUNK_SIZE)][];
    int start = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
        if(start + CHUNK_SIZE > source.length) {
            ret[i] = new byte[source.length-start];
            System.arraycopy(source, start, ret[i], 0, source.length - start);
        } 
        else {
            ret[i] = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
            System.arraycopy(source, start, ret[i], 0, CHUNK_SIZE);
        }
        start += CHUNK_SIZE ;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: How to divide bytes into 5 mb chunks using this ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, System.arraycopy(src, fromPos, dest, toPos, length) is generally considered faster than Arrays.copyOfRange.

```
byte[] source = ...read it from somewhere...;
byte[] newArray = new byte[64];
System.arraycopy(source, 0, newArray, 0, 64);
```

Comment: This is incorrect: it's not a matter of being faster, `Arrays.copyOfRange` also allocates a new `array` while `System.arraycopy` just copy elements in another `array` passed as parameter. So with second one you save the allocation.. that's why it is faster. If you check the definition of `Array.copyOfRange` you will see that it invokes `System.arraycopy`..

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

- `System.arraycopy(...)`
- `Array.copyOfRange(...)`

both of them work the same way but while first one only manages copy, second one is meant to be used to allocate the new chunk at the same time.

I benchmarked them with a result that `System.arraycopy` is faster if you manage to allocate chunks all together before splitting your array but slightly slower if you allocate them whle you copy: in this case you should use `Array.copyOfRange`.

Comment: Very interesting benchmark given that Array.copyOfRange() calls System.arraycopy: http://pastebin.com/SpSyx8Cd

Answer (score 0):

See [Arrays.copyOfRange](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29) for help. You could use this in a loop to split your array into several smaller chunks.

Answer (score 0):

This will do...

```
    byte[] source = new byte[2048];
    byte[] target = new byte[1024];  

// fill source with some data...

    Array.Copy(source, buffer, 1024);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another possible way of using `Arrays.copyOfRange` to divide a byte array in chunks (splitting the "data" in `blockSize` chunks):

```
byte[] data = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13 };
// Block size in bytes (default: 64k)
int blockSize = 64 * 1024;
int blockCount = (data.length + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;

byte[] range;

try {
  
    for (int i = 1; i < blockCount; i++) {
        int idx = (i - 1) * blockSize;
        range = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, idx, idx + blockSize);
        System.out.println("Chunk " + i + ": " Arrays.toString(range));
    }

} finally {
    
    // Last chunk
    int end = -1;
    if (data.length % blockSize == 0) {
            end = data.length;
    } else {
            end = data.length % blockSize + blockSize * (blockCount - 1);
    }
        
    range = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, (blockCount - 1) * blockSize, end);

    System.out.println("Chunk " + blockCount + ": " Arrays.toString(range));
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

Same as @Glenn answer but using streams (shorter, more readable)

```
public static byte[][] splitArrayIntoChunks(byte[] arrayToSplit, int chunkCount) {

    int chunkLength = arrayToSplit.length / chunkCount;

    return IntStream.range(0, chunkCount)
            .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayToSplit, i * chunkLength, (i + 1) * chunkLength))
            .toArray(byte[][]::new);

}
```