# Convert long to byte array and add it to another array

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion, long-integer

I want to change a values in byte array to put a long timestamp value in in the MSBs. Can someone tell me whats the best way to do it. I do not want to insert values bit-by-bit which I believe is very inefficient.

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
Long timeStamp = new Long(time);
byte[] bArray = new byte[128];
```

What I want is something like:

```
byte[0-63] = timeStamp.byteValue();
```

Is something like this possible . What is the best way to edit/insert values in this byte array. since byte is a primitive I dont think there are some direct implementations I can make use of?

Edit:
It seems that `System.currentTimeMillis()` is faster than `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()`, so replacing the above code by it.Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: This was helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399798/byte-array-and-int-conversion-in-java

Comment: I think you have the indices count wrong, check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399798/byte-array-and-int-conversion-in-java

Answer (score 136, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it:

- Use a [`ByteBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) (best option - concise and easy to read):

  ```
  byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.SIZE / Byte.SIZE).putLong(someLong).array();
  ```
- You can also use [`DataOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) (more verbose):

  ```
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
  dos.writeLong(someLong);
  dos.close();
  byte[] longBytes = baos.toByteArray();
  ```
- Finally, you can do this manually (taken from the `LongSerializer` in Hector's code) (harder to read):

  ```
  byte[] b = new byte[8];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    b[i] = (byte) (l >> (size - i - 1 << 3));
  }
  ```

Then you can append these bytes to your existing array by a simple loop:

```
// change this, if you want your long to start from 
// a different position in the array
int start = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < longBytes.length; i ++) {
   bytes[start + i] = longBytes[i];
}
```

Comment: thanks Bozho. I think this is what I was looking for . I think the first method would be faster than the later one. i am just concerned about the performance impact of using a ByteBuffer instead of byte array. This link talks more about the performance in the ned bytebuffer lib: http://jroller.com/cpurdy/date/20040405#raw_nio_performance ;  Also if the impact is not huge, can I just use ByteBuffer instead of a byte array ?

Comment: Use `ByteBuffer`. I doubt it will cause any problems.

Comment: I found that I had to set the order on the ByteByffer like so, Otherwise the bytes were the in an order reverse to what i was expecting byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putLong(bits).array();

Comment: I assume Java is [generally big endian](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981549/javas-virtual-machines-endianness), while x86 is little endian.

Comment: To avoid hardcoding the size of a long I would use `allocate(Long.SIZE)`

Comment: @mikejones Note that Long.SIZE will give you the number of bits used to represent Long (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#SIZE).  You'd need (Long.SIZE / Byte.SIZE) to match the example above.

Comment: @overthink Java 8 introduced a BYTES constant for this (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#BYTES).

Answer (score 22):

If you want to really get under the hood...

```
public byte[] longToByteArray(long value) {
    return new byte[] {
        (byte) (value >> 56),
        (byte) (value >> 48),
        (byte) (value >> 40),
        (byte) (value >> 32),
        (byte) (value >> 24),
        (byte) (value >> 16),
        (byte) (value >> 8),
        (byte) value
    };
}
```

Comment: From some testing of my own, the above longToByteArray solution executed about 5 times faster than ByteBuffer.allocate.putLong.array.

Answer (score 3):

For me ByteBuffer and other utils are expensive from time perspective. Here are 2 methods that you can use:

// first method (that is using the second method), it return the array allocated and fulfilled

```
public byte[] longToByteArray(long value) 
{
        byte[] array = new byte[8];

        longToByteArray(value,array,0);
        return array;
}
```

// this method is useful if you have already allocated the buffer and you want to write the long a specific location in the array.

```
public void longToByteArray(long value, byte[] array, int startFrom) 
{
    for (int i=7; i>=0; i--)
    {
        array[startFrom+7-i] = (byte) (value >> i*8);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you can slice a byte array to insert something into a subset without doing it byte by byte. Look at [Grab a segment of an array in Java without creating a new array on heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100371/does-java-allow-you-to-grab-a-segment-of-an-array) . Basically what I would do is set create a 64 byte array and set the time to it then append a blank 64 byte array to it. Or just do it byte by byte.

Answer (score 0):

I am updating this post because I have just announced a pre-release version of a library that will convert longs to byte arrays (and back again).  The library is very small and will convert any java primitive to a byte array.

http://rschilling.wordpress.com/2013/09/26/pre-release-announcement-pend-oreille/
http://code.google.com/p/pend-oreille/

If you use it you can do things like convert long arrays to byte arrays:

```
Double[] doubles = new Double[1000];
for (int i = 2; i < 1002; i++) {
    doubles[i - 2] = (double) i;
}

byte[] resultBytes1 = (byte[]) new PrimitiveHelper(PrimitiveUtil.unbox(doubles))
        .asType(byte[].class);
```

You can also convert a single long value as well.

```
byte[] resultBytes1 = (byte[]) new PrimitiveHelper(1000l)
        .asType(byte[].class);
```

Feel free to provide some feedback.

Update on October 4, 2013: 
I've now released the production of the library http://rschilling.wordpress.com/2013/10/04/pend-oreille-official-1-0-release/