# Get a BufferedImage from and OutputStream

Tags: java

I have a function, `int readFully(FileHandle handle, OutputStream out)`, which reads in an entire file from an SSH server and stores it in a local stream. I can write the file locally by using a `FileOutputStream` for the second parameter and then read that file into a `BufferedImage` using something like this:

```
bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/file"));
```

But how can I create the bufferedImage directly without first writing it to a file? I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435106/how-to-load-streamed-data-directly-into-a-bufferedimage), but still can't figure it out for my case.

Comment: What is this `FileHandle` class in the parameter?  If you can get an `InputStream` from it, then you can use `ImageIO.read(InputStream input)` method.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364936/input-and-output-stream-pipe-in-java

Comment: The `FileHandle` class holds some basic properties of the file, e.g. filename, path, permissions, etc. It doesn't have much functionality and I can't get an InputStream from it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead - you can then create a `ByteArrayInputStream` to read from the same byte array, and then pass that to [`ImageIO.read(InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29).

```
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
readFully(handle, output);
byte[] data = output.toByteArray();
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);
```

That's assuming you can't *actually* create an `InputStream` directly from the `FileHandle`, which would be even simpler.

Comment: Can you explain how to "create a `ByteArrayInputStream` to read from the same byte array"? Some example code would help. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Not sure who's answer to accept. I guess @JonSkeet's since his was first, but ssssteffff provided the details first.

Comment: No worry ;) I hesitated between Piped and ByteArray streams, I saw @JonSkeet answer so I mentioned Piped ones in my initial answer. Thanks to him, he pointed out a real issue before I tried to find why for hours, so he deserves it! :p

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `PipedInputStream` and a `PipedOutputStream` like this:

```
PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream();
PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream(pos);

readFully(handle, pos);

ImageIO.read(pis);
```

The piped output/input streams are linked, so what is "written" to `pos` will be readable from `pis`.

**EDIT**

Jon pointed out that the documentation states

> Attempting to use both objects from a single thread is not recommended as it may deadlock the thread.

You should not use this within the same thread. If you want a single thread code, you could use ByteArrayOutputStream / ByteArrayInputStream:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
readFully(handle, baos);

ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
```

All these classes (`PipedInputStream`, `PipedOutputStream`, `ByteArrayInputStream`, `ByteArrayOutputStream`) are present since JDK 1.0.

Comment: Nice - I always forget about those classes (hardly having used them myself). On the other hand, the documentation states: "Attempting to use both objects from a single thread is not recommended as it may deadlock the thread." Presumably there's a buffer within the stream... but I can't see a way of setting its size. (It would have to be big enough for the whole image.)

Comment: I tried this, but it hangs at the call to `readFully`. Perhaps due to the reasons Jon Skeet mentioned.

Comment: @KevinVW It's totally due to JonSkeet comment, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because piped I/O is such a good idea, but has a thread issue, the following theft from @ssssteffff.

```
    try {
        final PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream();
        PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream(out);

        new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    readFully(handle, out);
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        }.start();

        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);
        in.close();

        ...            
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

- Written is to `out` in a new thread.
- The piped input `in` is connected to out, waiting for its data.
- Probably more palatable in Java 8.