# How do I convert an array of longs to bytes in Scala?

Tags: scala

I want to md5 an `Array[Long]`, so I would like to make that an `Array[Byte]` because the MD5 function takes an `Array[Byte]`, how can I do that?

I use messagedigest for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html):

```
val arr = listOfLongs.
  foldLeft(ByteBuffer.allocate(8 * listOfLongs.size)){ (buffer, lon) => 
    buffer putLong lon
  }.array
```

Or more imperatively:

```
val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8 * listOfLongs.size)
listOfLongs.foreach(buffer putLong _)
val arr = buffer.array
```

Note: if you need little-endian, just call:

```
buffer.order(java.nio.ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
```

at the beginning. Fore more inspiration: [Convert long to byte array and add it to another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299111).