# ByteBuffer putLong() for long of 7-byte value

Tags: java, long-integer, bytebuffer, endianness

I have a `long`. I know this `long` is not very big. It could be encoded as an unsigned integer into 7 bytes, actually.

I would like to write my `long` into `byte[7]` using `ByteBuffer` and the little endian.

This

```
long myLong = ... //some value
byte[] myLongBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(7).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putLong(myLong).array();
```

throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, of course. Can I even do this with `ByteBuffer`? Should I do it in a different way?

Comment: actually long is 8 byte

Comment: @Pooya But I need to encode it into 7 bytes only, because I know the value is not that big... I simply don't need 8 bytes.

Comment: @vojta JVM doesn't know that and try to put 8 byte into 7 byte allocated buffer. you can simply use 8 bytes and then throw the most significant byte away (if it was positive ofcourse)

Comment: @Pooya Yes, of course, but I don't find it very efficient. I would have to allocate two arrays instead of one.

Comment: @Pooya And the code above is just an example, I need to write many values, the long is just one of many in the row.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299165/1737819

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Assuming little endian byte order as indicated in the OP)

(Assuming you want 56 least significant bits from the long being stored)

```
long myLong = someLongValue & 0x00FFFFFFFFFFFFFFL;
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(xxx).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
```

## Option A: Write 64 bit long and than remove one byte

```
bb.putLong(myLong);
bb.position(bb.position()-1);
```

for tail write (i.e. this long is the last write to the `ByteBuffer`):

```
bb.putLong(myLong);
bb.limit(bb.position()-1);
```

Beware that this approach works only if you can ensure the `ByteBuffer` capacity is large enough to fit this temporary extra byte.

Some example cases where this approach should be OK:

- where this 56bit value is always followed by another field (then you are sure there is some capacity reserve)
- when you are strictly using the `ByteBuffer.limit()` feature and not (ab)using the `ByteBuffer` for comfortable byte array writes (which is implied by your post)

## Option B: Write the long "per partes"

```
bb.putInt((int)myLong);
bb.putShort((short)(myLong>>>32));
bb.put((byte)(myLong>>>48));
```

This works every time.

## Option C: Use byte[] instead of long

You might consider using byte array instead of long (depends on your use case).

Good luck!

Comment: Option A is fine provide you don't mind writing one extra bytes, Option B is better if this is a problem.  Option C mean using the answer I gave. +1 for Option B

Answer (score 5):

You need to write a byte at a time such as (based on java.nio.Bits)

```
static private long makeLong(byte b6, byte b5, byte b4,
                             byte b3, byte b2, byte b1, byte b0)
{
    return ((((long)b6 & 0xff) << 48) |
            (((long)b5 & 0xff) << 40) |
            (((long)b4 & 0xff) << 32) |
            (((long)b3 & 0xff) << 24) |
            (((long)b2 & 0xff) << 16) |
            (((long)b1 & 0xff) <<  8) |
            (((long)b0 & 0xff)      ));
}

static long getLongL(ByteBuffer bb, int bi) {
    return makeLong(bb.get(bi + 6),
                    bb.get(bi + 5),
                    bb.get(bi + 4),
                    bb.get(bi + 3),
                    bb.get(bi + 2),
                    bb.get(bi + 1),
                    bb.get(bi    ));
}

private static byte long6(long x) { return (byte)(x >> 48); }
private static byte long5(long x) { return (byte)(x >> 40); }
private static byte long4(long x) { return (byte)(x >> 32); }
private static byte long3(long x) { return (byte)(x >> 24); }
private static byte long2(long x) { return (byte)(x >> 16); }
private static byte long1(long x) { return (byte)(x >>  8); }
private static byte long0(long x) { return (byte)(x      ); }

static void putLongL(ByteBuffer bb, int bi, long x) {
    bb.put(bi + 6, long6(x));
    bb.put(bi + 5, long5(x));
    bb.put(bi + 4, long4(x));
    bb.put(bi + 3, long3(x));
    bb.put(bi + 2, long2(x));
    bb.put(bi + 1, long1(x));
    bb.put(bi    , long0(x));
}
```

In general, I avoid making micro-optimisation like this as it adds complexity for little gain IMHO.  If you want to save space I suggest using something like stop bit encoding which uses one byte for every 7 bits. i.e. a long might only use 1 byte for small values but could be much larger as required.

Comment: @h22 you are welcome to shorten it. ;)  Reading/writing a 7 byte value isn't so trivial given there is no hardware support for it.

Answer (score -2):

Do as below

byte[] myLongBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.SIZE / Byte.SIZE).putLong(myLong).array();

Comment: But I need to encode it into 7 bytes only, because I know the value is not that big... I simply don't need 8 bytes.

Answer (score -2):

Java `long` is the 64 bit so 64/8 = 8 byte value so you are not allocating enough space to it. Allocate 8 bytes, not seven.

Comment: But I need to encode it into 7 bytes only, because I know the value is not that big... I simply don't need 8 bytes.

Comment: Then convert long into byte array and only write the last 7 bytes of that array to the buffer (highest byte goes first in Java). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485128/how-do-i-convert-long-to-byte-and-back-in-java on how to convert.