# How do you split a string array

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grabbing a segment of an array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100371/grabbing-a-segment-of-an-array-in-java)

I have a String[] which might contain 3, 6, 14 or 20 elements. I want to process 10 elements from the String[] array each time.

(e.g. for 3 or 6 it will loop once and twice for 14 or 20)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28boolean%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29%5C) to obtain subranges of your array.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this, assuming a `String[] array`:

```
int pos = 0;
while (pos + 10 < array.length) {
    // process array[pos] to array[pos + 9] here
    pos += 10;
}
// process array[pos] to array[array.length - 1] here
```

Answer (score 0):

Use thsi to loop one for each 10 Elements:

```
int index = 0;
while (index < array.length) do
{
  // process
  index = index + 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] arr={"h","e","l","l","o"};
List<String> li = Arrays.asList(arr);
final int divideBy=2;
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i+=divideBy){
    int endIndex=Math.min(i+divideBy,arr.length);
    System.out.println(li.subList(i,endIndex)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two nested loops:

```
    int[] nums = new int[14];
    // some initialization
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        nums[i] = i;
    }
    // processing your array in chunks of ten elements
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i += 10) {
        System.out.println("processing chunk number " + 
                (i / 10 + 1) + " of at most 10 nums");
        for (int j = i ; j < 10 * (i + 1) && j < nums.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(nums[j]);
        }
    }
```

Output is

```
processing chunk number 1 of at most 10 nums
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
processing chunk number 2 of at most 10 nums
10
11
12
13
```

I've used an `int[]` and not a `String[]`, but it's the same.