# Convert range of a Character[] to String

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have the array : `['a','b','c','d']`

I want to take a certain range of the array, say `[0,2]` and make this a string. The result would be `"abc"`.

This solution actually works :

```
private static String convertPartArrayToString(char[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    char[] dest = new char[endIndex - startIndex + 1];
    System.arraycopy( array, startIndex, dest, 0, endIndex - startIndex + 1 );
    return new String(dest);
}
```

But isn't there a way to make this faster than to copy the array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grab a segment of an array in Java without creating a new array on heap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100371/grab-a-segment-of-an-array-in-java-without-creating-a-new-array-on-heap)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283444/convert-array-of-strings-into-a-string-in-java

Comment: Given the fact that `String` is immutable you have to copy the (part of) the array

Comment: you can just use something like `return new String(array).substring(startIndex,endIndex);`

Comment: @alias_boubou That would copy the whole array and then copy only the subset required. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String has a constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[],%20int,%20int)) that takes an array of `char`, a `start` and `count`.

The array will still be (defensively) copied as otherwise mutable state will escape and you will no longer have an immutable `String`.

Comment: The reason I didn't use that is because I didn't know it existed! :p

Comment: Word of warning - The ctor (and the methods suggested by Jordi Castilla use an offset and a count, not a "to-from" as you use in your example. Not a large problem, but one to be aware off.

You will always have a defensive copy as otherwise the state will escape and the string will no longer be mutable.

It comes down to which reads better.  I'd use the ctor as I'm constructing a string. But that me.

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of JAVA built in methods, in this case you are using `System` API, wich is not really usual in this cases, instead of this you can use:

## [`Arrays API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html):

- [`toString(char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(char[]))
- [`copyRange(char[], int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(char[],%20int,%20int))

```
private static String convertPartArrayToString(char[] array, int from, int to) {  
    return Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyRange(array, from, to);
}
```

## [`String API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#copyValueOf(char[],%20int,%20int))

- [`copyValueOf(char[], int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#copyValueOf(char[],%20int,%20int))

```
private static String convertPartArrayToString(char[] array, int from, int to) {  
    return String.copyValueOf(array, from, to - from);
}
```

Comment: @mlk you are of course correct. And there is actually a shorter version `String.valueOf(array, from, count)`